# Passing uploaded file name to database in React

Tags: reactjs, file-upload, axios

I'm trying to implement file upload to my MERN app. I can upload the file, but have problem passing the file name to db. With the code below, file name is passed as "C:\fakepath\image.jpg" to db. File name is also stored at the filename state.  But I couldn't figure out how to pass it to the TextInput image value. Any ideas?

```
  const AddLocation = ({ addLocation }) => {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState({ title: '', image: '' });
  const [file, setFile] = useState('');
  const [filename, setFilename] = useState('Choose file');

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setLocation({ ...location, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onChangeFile = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);
    setLocation({ ...location, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const onSubmit = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('file', file);

    await axios.post('/upload', formData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    });

    addLocation(location);
  };

  return (
    <form>
      <TextInput name="title" value={location.title} onChange={onChange} />
      <TextInput
        name="image"
        type="file"
        label={filename}
        onChange={onChangeFile}
        value={location.image}
      />
      <Button onClick={onSubmit} node="button" type="submit">
        Submit
      </Button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

Comment: what is `addLocation` function?

Comment: `const res = await axios.post('/api/locations', location);
    const data = await res.data;
    dispatch({
      type: ADD_LOCATION,
      payload: data
    });`

Comment: Do you want to preview the file or just want to show the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have checked your code. When you selecting a file. File name is not showing in the `<TextInput/>`. So I have slightly change your code in `onChangeFile`,

```
  const onChangeFile = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
    setFilename(e.target.files[0].name);

    setLocation({
      ...location,
      image: e.target.value,
      title: e.target.files[0].name,
    });
  };
```

so with this image title is shown in the `<TextInput/>`. I hope this solves your issue.

**Updated**

When you calling `addLocation(location);` call it like this,

```
addLocation({
  ...location,
  image: fileName,
});
```

Comment: Not working, gives "Cannot read property '0' of null" error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-playground-forked-oybib?file=/src/index.js) its working fine here.

Comment: My aim is to pass the exact filename to db. With your code, it still passes as "C:\fakepath\image.jpg". But I want to pass only "image.jpg".

Comment: are you using title property or image property get the file name? location object's title property is already fulfilling your requirment.

Comment: If I console log e.target.value, it returns "C:\fakepath\image.jpg". If I console log filename state, it returns "image.jpg". I want to pass this one to db as a value for image input, not the fakepath one.

Comment: I have updated the answer, check if it's fixes your requirement.

Comment: I changed fileName to filename and it finally worked, thanks a lot my friend. :) I knew the solution was very simple, I just couldn't figure it out. Thanks for spending your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222383/discussion-between-keremcan-buyuktaskin-and-nazeer).